# App shows wrong Drawables

Tags: java, android, png, drawable, countdown

Hi i have a little Countdown Timer in my App which shows every second another Drawable.

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 if(millisUntilFinished <= 4000 && millisUntilFinished >= 3001 )
                 {
                     cdImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player1_countdown_3);
                     cdImage2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player2_countdown_3);
                 }
                 else if(millisUntilFinished <= 3000 && millisUntilFinished >= 2001 )
                 {
                     cdImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player1_countdown_2);
                     cdImage2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player2_countdown_2);
                 }
                 if (millisUntilFinished <= 2000 && millisUntilFinished >= 1000 )
                 {
                     cdImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player1_countdown_1);
                     cdImage2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player2_countdown_1);
                 }
                 if (millisUntilFinished <= 999 && millisUntilFinished >= 0 ) 
                 {
                     cdImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player1_countdown_go);
                     cdImage2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player2_countdown_go);
                 }
             }
```

but i also have the files
player1_countdown_4.png
player1_countdown_5.png
player1_countdown_6.png

and it shows this files instead of the right ones in the Order: 6,5,4,go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes this is an Eclipse error. You should try to clean your project and see if it helps. "Project -> Clean"